# Error "Invalid job id" when DAG is triggered manually from UI using BigQueryInsertJobOperator

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to trigger a stored procedure from composer using "BigQueryInsertJobOperator". The Dag runs fine when triggered as per schedule but it fails with below error when it is triggered manually from Airflow UI.
**Invalid jobID"airflow_DQ_create_stored_procedure_2021_11_02T01_36_02.229065_00_00_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX". Job IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores and dashes) and must be at most 1024 characters long.**
There are alphanumeric and '_' only in the job id created. It is not 1024 characters long.
Both Manual triggering and scheduled triggering should be possible. Please help!

**EDIT-1:**
It works if we configure job id from our end. But, it throws error if BQ automatically generates the job id.

Below is the code snippet:

````
from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator

yesterday = datetime.datetime.combine(
    datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(1),
    datetime.datetime.min.time())


default_dag_args = {
    'start_date': yesterday
}



with models.DAG(
'DQ_create',
schedule_interval ='@daily',
default_args = default_dag_args
) as dag:        

    Stored_Procedure = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='stored_procedure',
        configuration={
        "query": {
                "query": "CALL `project.dataset.procedure`() ",
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
},
)

Stored_Procedure```
````

Comment: There's a period in that job_id.

Comment: Hello Jason..Thanks for your time..That job id is being generated by Bigquery automatically..Does that mean there is a defect in Bigquery or am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right -- there IS a bug. Give me a few minutes to write this up as an answer so that I can harvest some sweet, sweet StackOverflow points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've found a bug in the BigQueryInsertJobOperator class. This class is responsible for constructing the job_id, which it does by taking the values of your DAG variables and concatenating them:

```
  exec_date = context['execution_date'].isoformat()
  job_id = f"airflow_{self.dag_id}_{self.task_id}_{exec_date}_{uniqueness_suffix}"
```

The "execution_date" you're using appears to have millisecond-level accuracy, which makes the `exec_date` variable have a period in it.

You have four options to fix this:

1. create a subclass of BigQueryInsertJobOperator that truncates its execution_date down to the second before it calls `super().execute(context)`. The resulting job_id string will have no period.
2. create a subclass of BigQueryInsertJobOperator that dynamically generates a unique job_id before it calls `super().execute(context)`
3. schedule your DAG to run at the top of minute (or at least the top of the second!), thereby forcing your execution_date to not have millisecond accuracy
4. upgrade to Airflow v2.0. They've fixed this bug by stripping out the period.(https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/47b05a87f004dc273a4757ba49f03808a86f77e7#diff-529929b4ca60ce73b8da0f45d8a5c43c2d4e391b913fe78b39892899f812951e)